# Add attribute to attribute set

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, attribute-set

I have an existent attribute and i want to add it to an attribute set. I drag and drop the attribute to a group. What database tables should i change to complete the process ?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't required database table update for set attribute to attribute set. You have to do reindexing to get update in admin product page.

Go to 
Admin panel, `System -> Index Management`
Reindexing all index and check.

Comment: I did a `--reindexall`. The attribute is visible in the side when i try to edit a product, but when i try to get it using `$_product->getAttribute()` after setting to some value and successfully save it, it returns nothing. the other original attributes are called normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think the table you are looking for is `eav_attribute` table.

`SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'your attribute'`

But the problem you are having, it could be that you are not loading the product Model properly, or you are unable to return the value of the attribute because it is not on the flat.
First of all, enable the flat tables ‘Use flat catalog products’ in System -> Config -> Catalog
And then, in your attribute, enable the ‘Used in product listing’ setting in Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes